# Find the volume with integral of object bounded by z = 0, z = x*y, z + x + y = 1;

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I need to find the volume of z = 0; z+x+y = 1; z = x*y.[The object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8hR0.png).
But I cannot make limits for the integral.I can make this integral [The integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVugQ.png).
But it will  mean that we find this piece of object[Whole object that is needed to substract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ROyd.png).
So can you explain to me how to find this piece of object and then substract [Piece of object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJmRx.png) or make a new one integral for whole this object.
The answer must be 17/12-2ln(2) = 0.03

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are some helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I meant that z = 0 is a plane on Z axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for a fixed value of $x$ which ca n varies from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$.  In between $0$ and $1$, the courses form a triangle with height and base length calculated as below.

$$z = xy$$
$$y + z = 1 - x$$

Solving this equations we have

$$y = \frac{1 - x}{1 + x}$$
$$z = \frac{x(1 - x)}{1 + x}$$

The height of the above triangle is given by the $y$ value above and the base is the y intercept given by $(1 - x)$.

Hence the volume is given by

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2}\frac{x(1 - x)}{1 + x}(1 - x) dx = \frac{17}{12} - 2ln2$$

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helps me